# how to use assertThrows

Tags: junit5, assert

```
@Test
public void testStudent(){
   String name = "Anna";
   StudentException studentException = assertThrows(StudentException.class, () -> student.findName(name));
}
```

When we use assertThrow, what's the basic knowledge to write in this way: `StudentException.class, () -> student.findName(name)`? And what does `()` mean in the code?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking what a _lambda_ is?

Comment: Is it lambda? Why use ```()```  here?

Comment: Which parentheses are you asking about? You certainly have a lambda there, maybe you should read up on that syntax to see if it's what is confusing you.

Comment: The parentheses after `StudentException.class`. I'm confusing why we use parentheses directly after `StudentException.class` and is there any default value for this parentheses.

Comment: Then yes, that's part of the lambda syntax. Again I'd suggest reading about that.